# PhantomJs cannot execute binary file

Tags: php, laravel-5, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJs in my laravel 5 project. I have downloaded via composer. I have added into my providers section and aliases section within config/app.php

Okay so i have now created my controller as seen below:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use PDF;
use View;

class PdfController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $view = View::make('home');

        return PDF::createFromView($view, 'home.pdf');
    }
}
```

I have also created my route for this method. However when i try this in my browser it throws the following error:

PhantomJS: sh: /Users/matts/sites/ManagementApp/vendor/antking/phantom-pdf/src/../bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending the appropriate headers

Comment: Im not sure, i followed a tutorial step by step and got this error

Answer (score 1):

The "cannot execute binary file" indicates that it was not able to run phantomjs at all, and it is probably not related to your code. The most likely reason for this is an architecture incompatibility. Depending on whether or not you have a 32 or 64 bit system, you should use either phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 (64bit) or phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-i686. It is possible that you used the wrong one for your system.